# save position of robot online slam?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I want to save the current position of robot while the navigation with online slam is running and then i can set those saved position as 2d goals in navigation with static map!

i can get current position of the robot in map frame when i am running navigation stack with static map by subscribing to amcl/pose topic. but in navigation with online slam amcl does not publishes any point.
So how can i get robots current position in online slam?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30324/save-position-of-robot-online-slam?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping), the robot's pose is published via a tf. You can use [tf_echo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#tf_echo) to display this transformation:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link
```

You may also try out [hector_trajectory_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_trajectory_server) for saving and retrieving the traveled trajectory.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-03-23**:
Here the link to the TF tutorials: http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2012-03-23**:
I tried out rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link and its result was very good! but i will test hector_trajectory_server too! thanks for your answer!